# jQuery ajax call with multiple success events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page that does a jQuery ajax call to my FCGI server. I would like the server to 'update' the browser every X seconds whilst it is processing data.

I had a go at this, but whatever I try, `success()` is only ever called when the FCGIServer is completely finished sending its response even though my browser sees the '200 - OK' header the first time that server responds.

I understood that `success()` will be triggered when

- The 200 - OK header is read and
- Data which adheres to the 'dataType'
  set in the ajax call

Is this at all possible? And if not then why do both success() and complete() exist as they would be indicating the same event(?).

Comment: A request will only ever complete once. To do what you require you would need to make multiple requests - one to do the work and then subsequent ones on a timer to check the progress of the logic being executed (which you would need to keep track of yourself, this isn't out of the box behaviour). `success` exists to run code when the request completes successfully. `complete` exists to run code when the request is finished, no matter what it's return state was.

Comment: complete() always gets called regardles of success or fail